# Checking version of node on macOS

Tags: node.js, macos

I wanted to check the version of node js on my machine. It gives two different numbers:

```
/usr/local/n/versions/node$ ls
14.16.1

/usr/local/n/versions/node$ node -v
v8.9.4
```

Are there two different versions?

Answer (score 1):

We can have different nodejs versions on the same machine, but there is only 1 active version for a user at the same time.

Your command `node -v` give you the NodeJS active version, which is v8.9.4.
The `ls` command give you only the content of the folder. NodeJS v14.16.1 is installed on your machine, but is not active.

Comment: Thanks. I found that there are two nodes installed.